# Display the table names in a select statement instead of IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a table (gridview) appearing, once a 'patient' logs in they can see their orders that they have placed (the order table/ Order_pres).

The order table contains a list of foreign keys all from other tables i.e Patient Id from the Patient table and PharmacyId from the pharmacy table:

[image: orders]

In the patient/ doctor/ pharmacy tables these all have names - I want my statement to show the names instead of the Ids in the table as the names would make more sense than viewing a code. Order Id would stay the same (as an Id) as it is only part of the Order_pres table.

```
 If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\surgerydb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")


            Dim cmd2string As String = "SELECT * FROM [Order_pres]"
            Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()
            Dim da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd2string, conn)
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PatientId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Session("PatientId").ToString())
            conn.Open()
            da.Fill(dt)
            conn.Close()

            GridVieworders.DataSource = dt
            GridVieworders.DataBind()
        End If
```

**OrderId** - will stay the same and comes from the order_pres table

**PatientId** comes from the Patient table and I want to get 'Forename' 
and 'Surname' from the table connected to Patient Id.

**MedicineId** comes from the medicine table and I want to get 'Name'

**Pharmacy** - Comes from the pharmacy table and I want to get 'pharmname'

**Doctor** - comes from the Doctor table and I want to get 'Name'

**Date ordered** - comes from the Order_pres and will stay the same

hopefully someone can help. Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

You'll notice two things.
1) Using a LEFT JOIN in case one or more of the key IDs are not populated

2) Joining to SOMEFIELD, you didn't specify the primary key on the supplemental tables

```
Select A.OrderID
      ,A.PatientId 
      ,B.Forename
      ,B.Surname
      ,A.MedicineId  
      ,C.Name      as MedicineName
      ,A.Pharmacy 
      ,D.pharmname 
      ,A.DoctorID
      ,E.Name as DoctorName
      ,A.DateOrderd
 From  order_pres  A
 Left  Join Patient   B on (A.PatientId  = B.SomeField)
 Left  Join medicine  C on (A.MedicineId = C.SomeField)
 Left  Join pharmacy  D on (A.Pharmacy   = D.SomeField) 
 Left  Join Doctor    E on (A.DoctorID   = E.SomeField)
```

Comment: Hi John! thank you for taking the time to answer this question - in this answer I would be using (for example)  OrderId as A and not actually including A in the statement   Ie   -  Left  Join Patient   PatientId on (Forename.PatientId  = Patient.Forename)   - sorry I am just abit confussed

Comment: the primary key is order ID

Comment: Your choice.  I just prefer using aliases, it tends to be more readable for me, and more concise.

Comment: SomeField should be the key in (for example) the Patient

Comment: the primary keys are all the Ids in the tables - Patient table would be PatientId  - and dateordered belongs to the Order_pres table so its primary key would be OrderId

Comment: Sorry I am quite confussed how to apply this John

Comment: In my tables also (doctor table and medicine table) both the fields are Name - so I have to use As medicinename ?

Comment: Correct, you can see in my example C.Name AS MedicineName and E.Name as DoctorName.   This is to avoid "ambiguous field name"

Comment: Just noticed I had a typo  A.DateOrderd  should be DateOrdered

Comment: So to FIX the joins,  it would be (A.PatientId  = B.PatientId)    if PatientID is the pk in the patient table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116268/discussion-between-laurajs-and-john-cappelletti).